# check column for specific character position and populate another column

Tags: excel-formula

I have a column of machine names.  Management want a separate column to say "Desktop" or "Laptop" instead.  Now the 5th character is what I can check to differentiate.  I've tried searching and cannot find the right code.  My machine name is column I and column H will need to have the right formula to display desktop or laptop.  It's about 1300 rows.  Any suggestions are appreciated?

Jeff

Comment: The [MID](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/mid-midb-functions-HP010342690.aspx) function is what you are looking for. e.g. `=IF(MID(I2, 5, 1)="D", "Desktop", "Laptop")`

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of an answer, quoting @Jeeped:

> The MID function is what you are looking for. e.g. =IF(MID(I2, 5, 1)="D", "Desktop", "Laptop")